# MongoDB MapReduce : use positional operator $ in map function

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a collection with entries that look like that :

{"userid": 1, "contents": [ { "tag": "whatever", "value": 100 },  {"tag": "whatever2", "value": 110 } ] }

I'm performing a MapReduce on this collection with queries such as {"contents.tag": "whatever"}.

What I'd like to do in my map function is emiting the field "value" corresponding to the entry in the array "contents" that matched the query **without having to iterate through the whole array**. Under normal circumstances, I could do that using the $ positional operator with something like contents.$.value. But in the MapReduce case, it's not working.

To summarize, here is the code I have right now :`

```
map=function(){
        emit(this.userid, WHAT DO I WRITE HERE TO EMIT THE VALUE I WANT ?);
    }
    reduce=function(key,values){
        return values[0]; //this reduce function does not make sense, just for the example
    }
    res=db.runCommand(
    {
        "mapreduce": "collection",
        "query": {'contents.tag':'whatever'},
        "map": map,
        "reduce": reduce,
        "out": "test_mr" 
    }
    );`
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work without iterating over the whole array. In MongoDB a query is intended to match an entire document.

When dealing with Map / Reduce, the query is simply trimming the number of documents that are passed into the `map` function. However, the `map` function has no knowledge of the query that was run. The two are disconnected.

The source code around the M/R is [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r1.9.0/db/commands/mr.cpp#L849).

There is an upcoming aggregation feature that will more closely match this desire. But there's no timeline on this feature.

Comment: That's what I was thinking ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

No way. I've had the same problem. The iterate is necessary.
You could do this:

```
map=function() {
  for(var i in this.contents) {
    if(this.contents[i].tag == "whatever") {
      emit(this.userid, this.contents[i].value);
    }
  } 
}
```